# Spring Boot DevTools does not work well with Gradle

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-devtools

I followed instructions from Spring website to try Spring DevTools and I cannot see the updated changes, even when i refresh my page.

I tried to include dependencies in build Gradle, but still fail. Many answers on Stack Overflow are outdated.

Comment: For Gradle Spring Boot projects, you need to:
 1. Add this line to 'dependencies' of build.gradle  
 developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'  

 2. Right click on project > Gradle > Refresh Gradle Project, for the gradle libraries to link to project  

 3. Start your Spring Boot app, to see the DevTool changs  

 4. Edit any .html in IDE, then refresh the page in browser, to see changes

Comment: There is far too little information. How are you running the application? Using Gradle? Using your IDE? If the latter which IDE?